# Replacement class for sun.misc.Service

Tags: java, java-9

I have some old (pre java 6) code that depends on the `sun.misc.Service` API, such as:

```
sun.misc.Service.providers(MyServiceProvider.class);
```

This class is being removed (not just internalized) in Java 9.

What alternate Java SE API can I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `sun.misc.Service` class has been replaced by `java.util.ServiceLoader` in Java 6.

The following code examples are equivalent:

**Before**

```
Iterator<MyServiceProvider> = sun.misc.Service.providers(MyServiceProvider.class);
```

**After**

```
Iterator<MyServiceProvider> = java.util.ServiceLoader.load(MyServiceProvider.class).iterator();
```

As those in comments have pointed out, java.util.ServiceLoader has been around for a long time (Java 6).

Comment: `java.util.ServiceLoader` has been there since Java 1.6.

Comment: @EJP yep, the code I have pre-dates java 6.  Just documenting the removal of this API and what its substitute is (since jdeps didn't).  This is one instance where code that has been working for many years will start failing in java 9.